# Concatenate all values of field in Data.Table R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to collapse the value of field `Value_From` of below data set using below expression

```
dt [ , unique(Value_From) , by = c("From_Type","To_Type") ][ , .(val = list(c(V1)) , `Unique_From_IDs` = .N ) , by = c("From_Type","To_Type")]
```

[image]

However when I run this some of the values are getting dropped and I am getting below results

[image]

Please help me understand why some of the ID's are getting dropped.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you sure they're getting dropped, and they aren't just not printing?

Comment: You should print the `val` column value. Doesn't seem like they are getting dropped.

Comment: They're just not printing. It maxes out at six. It's #14 on this list https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1523

Comment: @bk18 Well i extracted the values and was able to retrieve all of them, thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, to the comments above, try:

```
dt [ , unique(Value_From) , by = c("From_Type","To_Type") ][ , .(val = list(list(V1)) , `Unique_From_IDs` = .N ) , by = c("From_Type","To_Type")]
```

The double `list()` call will make your table look like:

```
... ... listCol
... ... <list>
```

This way you won't encounter the somewhat confusing problem of abbreviation.